# Final argument to `executeLegacyOperation` must be a callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

Not sure to describe the issue but we are trying to upgrade to mongoDB 5.0 and have updated mongoose to 6.0.12 in the process of upgrading mongoDB. In running the batch tests (jest), we are stuck on the error message "Final argument to `executeLegacyOperation` must be a callback"

The entire message is :

```
Failed: Array [
      GraphQLError {
        "locations": Array [
          [Object],
        ],
        "message": "Final argument to `executeLegacyOperation` must be a callback",
        "path": Array [
          "upsertBatchRole",
        ],
      },
    ]
```

An example of a test that is failing:

```
        test('should update existing items and return UPDATED status', async () => {
            const {
                data: { upsertBatchRole },
            } = await gqlClient.fetch<{ upsertBatchRole: GQLUpsertBatchRoleOutput }>(upsertBatchRoleMutation, {
                condition: {},
                input: [
                    {
                        name: 'new',
                        id: '57',
                    },
                ],
            });

            expect(upsertBatchRole).not.toBeNull();
            const { status, data } = upsertBatchRole as GQLUpsertBatchRoleOutput;

            const unitedData = uniteCategorizedArrays<GQLRole>({ ...data });

            expect(status).toBe(ms.UPDATED);
            expect(unitedData.length).toBe(1);
            expect(unitedData[0]).toHaveProperty('name');
            expect(unitedData[0]?.name).toBe('new');
            _.forEach(unitedData, (item) => {
                expect(item).toHaveProperty('id');
                expect(item).toHaveProperty('name');
            });

            const {
                data: { roleList },
            } = await gqlClient.fetch(`
                roleList {
                    name
                }
            `);
            const orderedList = _.sortBy(roleList, 'name');
            expect(orderedList).toHaveLength(1);
            expect(orderedList[0].name).toBe('new');
        });
```

Currently, graphql is at 15.5.1. Tried to upgrade graphql and got as far as 15.8.0 as higher versions produced a different error. Current node version is 14.21.3

Not sure if graphql is the issue here so looking for any ideas on how to resolve the above issue.

**UPDATED**

Here is a code snippet from upsertBatchEntity.js:

```
async function updateBatchEntity(Collection, entitiesToUpdate, gqlInfo) {
    if (_.isEmpty(entitiesToUpdate)) return { status: ms.UPDATED, data: [] };

    const transactionSession = getCurrentTransactionSessionFromGQLInfo(gqlInfo);

    const bulkUpdate = Collection.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp({
        session: transactionSession,
    });

    _.forEach(entitiesToUpdate, (entity) => {
        const _id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(entity._id);
        const entityProperties = _.omit(entity, ['id', '_id']);

        const convertedEntityProperties = convertEntityPropertiesToObjectIdWhereNeeded(Collection, entityProperties);

        bulkUpdate.find({ _id }).updateOne({ $set: { ...convertedEntityProperties, updatedAt: new Date() } });
    });

    await bulkUpdate.execute(null, { session: transactionSession });
    clearEntityLoadersCache(Collection.modelName, gqlInfo);

    return {
        status: ms.UPDATED,
        data: entitiesToUpdate,
    };
}
```

Comment: `executeLegacyOperation` is from the MongoDB source and that message can be found there as well [utils.ts](https://unpkg.com/browse/mongodb@4.2.2/src/utils.ts). Your GraphQL server (Apollo?) shouldn't be calling mongo directly so look in your `upsertBatchRole` code to see how it's using Mongo and if anything needs to be changed relative to Mongo 5.0

Comment: Thanks @MichelFloyd for the response. I've updated the description with details of the `upsertBatchRole` plus added another test that works. Maybe it's my lack of MongoDB knowledge, but I still don't see anything that needs to be changed relative to Mongo 5.0

Comment: Can you include the mutation code for `upsertBatchRole` where you call Mongo? That's where the error is likely occurring.

Comment: I thought I did provide the mutation code in the ***UPDATED*** section of the details above. (Apparently, my stack overflow formatting skills are not refined yet either)

Comment: You provided the GraphQL mutation definition but not your js code that implements the mutation and talks to Mongo.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Relatively new to MongoDB and NodeJS so somewhat ignorant on certain technical aspects. I'll try to find the js code that implements the mutation, although I'm not sure where to look

Comment: I'm unable to find the implementation in the js code. It only seems to be referenced in the test. Also, I didn't mention in my original post that this is not the only test that us failing as there are a total of 583 failed tests (in 30 test suites), that generally indicate the same error.

Comment: Look for `upsertBatchRole` in the source. That's going to be a js function that calls Mongo.

Comment: This is all I could find but don't think it's what you are asking for:

`export const upsertBatchRole = '
    mutation upsertBatchRole($input: [UpsertBatchRoleInput], $condition: UpsertBatchRoleCondition) {
        upsertBatchRole(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
            status,
            data {
                id
            }
        }
    }
';`

Comment: Nope - that's the gql query, not the resolver. You need to go one level deeper into your code.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help @MichelFloyd. Did a quick check and noticed that my util.ts under mongodb does not contain the `executeLegacyOperation` method. Also, did not find any resolvers for `upsertBatchRole` - only reference to a resolver I found was `upsertBatchRole?: Resolver<GQLResolversTypes['UpsertBatchRoleOutput'], ParentType, ContextType, RequireFields<GQLRootMutationType_UpsertBatchRoleArgs, never>>;`

Comment: That's the typescript definition of the resolver. The code has to be in your code base somewhere because the resolver is throwing the error. You could potentially find it using your debugger.

Comment: I think I'm going crazy as I can't find *any* js file named `upsertBatchRule` (Debugging doesn't seem to work)

Comment: Not sure if this is relavant but I noticed mongodb is under mongoose (node_modules > mongoose > node_modules > mongodb > utils) Mongoose is using the mongodb driver v4.1.3

Comment: There's got to be some ts or js code of yours that implements the mutation.  Find that.

Comment: I was talking to the lead developer and got some more details from him. He guided me to where to look in the code and mentioned that GQL calls mongoose which then calls the DB. I've updated the description with `upsertBatchEntity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `updateOne()` is async and expects a callback - [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#Query.prototype.updateOne())

Where you are doing:

```
bulkUpdate.find({ _id }).updateOne({ $set: { ...convertedEntityProperties, updatedAt: new Date() } });
```

You'll need to provide a callback or possibly just `await` it.

Comment: Thanks. I added an await and it seems to have fixed the problem of `executeLegacyOperation`  as that message no longer appears. At least I hope so as the test is still failing but on the expected result vs received. Still needs further investigation.

Comment: I will accept your answer but still have one more question. The code seems to be failing on the `bulkUpdate.execute(...)` and if I remove it, the code runs so do I really need it since the `updateOne` seems to be working? (I still have to test the application)

Comment: It looks like that `bulkUpdate.execute()` commits the transaction so I'm pretty sure it's necessary!!

Comment: Ha ha. Of course it's needed. That was dumb of me. I forgot to mention there was a comment before this line (that I removed prior to posting) but I've managed to get it working now. Thanks again for your help