# MongoBulkWriteError: Transaction has been aborted

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this function that is used to bulk update but when running a test, various transactions are aborted. There is no pattern either as the error is in the form of "MongoBulkWriteError: Transaction ?? has been aborted" where ?? could be any number and could one or multiple messages. (It runs *occasionally* without any error messages)

How do I resolve the transaction(s) being aborted?

```
async function updateBatchEntity(Collection, entitiesToUpdate, gqlInfo) {
    if (_.isEmpty(entitiesToUpdate)) return { status: ms.UPDATED, data: [] };

    const transactionSession = getCurrentTransactionSessionFromGQLInfo(gqlInfo);

    const bulkUpdate = Collection.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp({
        session: transactionSession,
    });

    try {
        for (const entity of entitiesToUpdate) {
            const _id = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(entity._id);
            const entityProperties = _.omit(entity, ['id', '_id']);
            const convertedEntityProperties = convertEntityPropertiesToObjectIdWhereNeeded(
                Collection,
                entityProperties
            );
            await bulkUpdate.find({ _id }).updateOne({ $set: { ...convertedEntityProperties, updatedAt: new Date() } });
        }

        bulkUpdate.execute();
        clearEntityLoadersCache(Collection.modelName, gqlInfo);

        return {
            status: ms.UPDATED,
            data: entitiesToUpdate,
        };
    } catch (error) {
        // Handle error
        console.error('Error updating entities:', error);
        return { status: ms.ERROR, error: 'Failed to update entities.' };
    }
}
```

This is the test

```
        describe(`upsertBatch ${modelType} transaction`, () => {
            const alwaysAbortedUpsertBatchResolver = resolverWithTransaction(
                alwaysAbort(getUpsertBatchResolver(modelType))
            );
            const testModelDocument2 = getDocumentFromSchema(modelSchema);

            test(`should revert changes made by update batch ${modelName} document`, async () => {
                const initialDocuments = [testModelDocument, testModelDocument2];
                const {
                    data: { insertedValues },
                } = await getUpsertBatchResolver(modelType)(root, { input: initialDocuments });

                expect(insertedValues).toHaveLength(2);

                const fieldToUpdate = Object.keys(modelSchema)[0];
                if (!fieldToUpdate) throw new Error('no field to update');
                const updatedDocuments = [testModelDocument, testModelDocument2].map((document, index) => ({
                    ...updateDocument(document, modelSchema, fieldToUpdate),
                    _id: insertedValues[index]._id.toString(),
                }));

                const { originalResult } = await alwaysAbortedUpsertBatchResolver(
                    root,
                    { input: updatedDocuments },
                    context,
                    gqlInfo
                );

                expect(originalResult.status).toBe(UPDATED);

                const documentsAfterAbortedUpdate: DocumentData[] = await getList(
                    modelName,
                    { id: { $in: updatedDocuments.map((doc) => doc._id) } },
                    projection,
                    gqlInfo
                );

                documentsAfterAbortedUpdate.forEach((document, index) => {
                    expect(document[fieldToUpdate]).toStrictEqual(initialDocuments[index]?.[fieldToUpdate]);
                });
            });

            test(`should revert changes made by insert batch ${modelName} document`, async () => {
                const { originalResult } = await alwaysAbortedUpsertBatchResolver(
                    root,
                    { input: [testModelDocument, testModelDocument2] },
                    context,
                    gqlInfo
                );
                expect(originalResult.status).toBe(INSERTED);
                const documentAfterAbortedUpdate = await getList(modelName, {}, projection, gqlInfo);
                expect(documentAfterAbortedUpdate).toStrictEqual([]);
            });
        });
```

**Note:** This is a fallout from a previous question I posted: [Final argument to `executeLegacyOperation` must be a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77749124/final-argument-to-executelegacyoperation-must-be-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered my own question. I simply added an `await` statement on the execute and it *seems* to have solved the issue.

```
await bulkUpdate.execute();
```